# how to animate an element with a sticky position

Tags: javascript, css, sticky

Tell me how to animate an element with a sticky position

I want the animation not to play in the initial position, but when the element is in motion, the animation goes smoothly to the top value.

let's say rotate(900deg);
and depending on where we scrolled, down or up, the direction of the animation changed.

I understand that you can track the initial coordinates of an element in a block and if some value is added to the coordinates along the Y axis, then we start scrolling, but I can’t implement this so that
in the initial position rotate was 0 and in the final position 900, which would allow the animation to play at different speeds at different scrolling speeds

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: -moz-max-content;
  height: max-content;
  background: rgb(22, 22, 22);
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: -moz-max-content;
  height: max-content;
}

.main__start-page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: palegreen;
}

.main__start-page p:first-child {
  font-size: 114px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}

.main__start-page p:last-child {
  font-size: 114px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}

.main__center-page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: plum;
}

.main__end-page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: palegoldenrod;
}

.main__lorem-center-page {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  & p {
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
}

.main__wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: max-content;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.asterisk__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50%;
}

.asterisk__wrapper::before {
  content: "start";
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
}

.asterisk__wrapper::after {
  content: "stop";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -60px;
}

.asterisk {
  font-size: 500px;
  position: sticky;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 99px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main__wrapper">
    <div class="main__start-page">
      <p>ПРИВЕТ</p>
      <p>МИР</p>
    </div>

    <div class="main__center-page">
      <div class="main__lorem-center-page">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit deserunt, eaque laudantium inventore magni perferendis saepe reprehenderit possimus quam rerum officia quis veritatis cum est, esse sapiente tempora voluptatum tempore!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="asterisk__wrapper">
      <div class="asterisk"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main__end-page">
    <div class="main__lorem-center-page">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi aperiam alias fugiat itaque dicta cumque sed soluta possimus reiciendis. Quidem ad voluptatum possimus labore iure magnam quaerat non minus dolore.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an approximated answer, we get the difference between the scroll position and bottom position (whichever is smaller) then minus the top, the max value of this calculation is 253.54 which I converted to a ratio of 3.549, so that the min value will be zero and max will be 900

```js
const asterisk = document.getElementsByClassName('asterisk')[0];
const initial =  window.scrollY;
const asteriskWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('asterisk__wrapper')[0];
const { bottom: bottomY, height: topY } = asteriskWrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
document.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  lastKnownScrollPosition = window.scrollY + topY;
  const rotateValue = Math.round((Math.min(window.scrollY + topY, bottomY) - topY) * 3.549); // 900 / 253.54 (max val of ratio) = 3.549
  asterisk.style.transform = `rotate(${rotateValue}deg)`;
  
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: -moz-max-content;
  height: max-content;
  background: rgb(22, 22, 22);
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: -moz-max-content;
  height: max-content;
}

.main__start-page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: palegreen;
}

.main__start-page p:first-child {
  font-size: 114px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}

.main__start-page p:last-child {
  font-size: 114px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}

.main__center-page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: plum;
}

.main__end-page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: palegoldenrod;
}

.main__lorem-center-page {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  & p {
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
}

.main__wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: max-content;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.asterisk__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50%;
}

.asterisk__wrapper::before {
  content: "start";
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
}

.asterisk__wrapper::after {
  content: "stop";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -60px;
}

.asterisk {
  font-size: 12px;
  position: sticky;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 99px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main__wrapper">
    <div class="main__start-page">
      <p>ПРИВЕТ</p>
      <p>МИР</p>
    </div>

    <div class="main__center-page">
      <div class="main__lorem-center-page">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit deserunt, eaque laudantium inventore magni perferendis saepe reprehenderit possimus quam rerum officia quis veritatis cum est, esse sapiente tempora voluptatum tempore!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="asterisk__wrapper">
      <div class="asterisk">a</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main__end-page">
    <div class="main__lorem-center-page">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi aperiam alias fugiat itaque dicta cumque sed soluta possimus reiciendis. Quidem ad voluptatum possimus labore iure magnam quaerat non minus dolore.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood the logic and I think I’ll modify it to suit my needs.